# Understanding the logic of using the any() argument

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that contains only 1s and 0s and looks like this (in reality I have several more columns):

```
Test A B C D E
0    1 1 0 1 0
0    0 1 0 1 0
0    0 0 0 1 0
1    1 0 1 1 0
```

I first look at just the first column and check each row to return True if there is a one and False if there is a zero.  I then look at the first two columns and check each row to return True if at least one of the values is a 1 and False if not.  I continue in this manner, adding a column each time.

My code is:

```
for i in range(0,len(df.columns)):
    print(df.iloc[:,0:0+i].any(axis=1))
```

For the first column, it returns False, False, False, False. I don't understand why this is considering that my final value in the Test column is a 1.  Why is it not returning False, False, False, True?

Reproducible data:

```
data = {'Test': [0, 0, 0, 1],
    'A': [1, 0, 0, 1],
   'B':[1,1,0,0],
   'C':[0,0,0,1],
   'D':[1,1,1,1],
   'E':[0,0,0,0]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you started your column slicing at 1 instead of 0, you are skipping the `test` column.

`df.iloc[:,0:1+i].any(axis=1)` (notice it starts at 0 now)

This small correction should make it works as intended.